# I wrote code in Flutter. But Shape plus not working but Image Picker working

Tags: flutter, share, imagepicker, share-plus

I use Flutter and added Image Picker and Share Plus.
Image Picker working but doesnt work Share Plus?
I dont understand why doesnt working share plus.
Can you looking?

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(share1());
}

class share1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const share1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Image Share",
      home: share2(),
    );
  }
}

class share2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const share2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);



  @override
  State<share2> createState() => _share2State();
}

class _share2State extends State<share2> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  File? _image;

Future getImage(ImageSource source) async {
  try {
    final image=await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
    if(image==null) return;

    final imageTemporary = File(image.path);
    
    setState(() {
      this._image=imageTemporary;
      Share.share(_image);
    });


  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print('Failed to pick image : $e');
  }
}



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(centerTitle:true,title: Text("Image Share"),),
      body: Center(child: Column(children: [
        SizedBox(height: 40,),
        _image != null ? Image.file(_image!,width: 250,height: 250,fit: BoxFit.cover,)
            : Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
        SizedBox(height: 40,),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: ()=> getImage(ImageSource.gallery), child: Text("Resim Seç")),
        Text("Image Share"),

      ],),),
    );
  }
}
```

Purpose of the project : Adding and sharing pictures from the gallery. However, I couldn't get it to run.Any idea where is wrong with my code and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
void shareFile() {
  final imagepick = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source:ImageSource.gallery);

  if(imagepick == null) {
    return;
  }

  await Share.shareFiles([imagepick.path]);
}
```